# Providing Terraform with credentials in terraform files instead of env variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have set-up a terraform project with a remote back-end on GCP. Now when I want to deploy the infrastructure, I run into issues with credentials. I have a credentials file in

```
\home\mike\.config\gcloud\credentials.json
```

In my terraform project I have the following data referring to the remote state:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "project_id" {
   backend   = "gcs"
   workspace = "${terraform.workspace}"

   config {
     bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
     prefix = "${var.prefix_project}"
   }
}
```

and I specify the cloud provider with a the details of my credentials file.

```
provider "google" {
  version     = "~> 1.16"
  project     = "${data.terraform_remote_state.project_id.project_id}"
  region      = "${var.region}"
  credentials = "${file(var.credentials)}"
}
```

However, this runs into

```
data.terraform_remote_state.project_id: data.terraform_remote_state.project_id: 
error initializing backend:
storage.NewClient() failed: dialing: google: could not find default 
credentials.
```

if I add

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/mike/.config/gcloud/credentials.json
```

I do get it to run as desired. My issue is that I would like to specify the credentials in the terraform files as I am running the terraform commands in an automated way from a python script where I cannot set the environment variables. How can I let terraform know where the credentials are without setting the env variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this out in the end.

Also the data needs to have the credentials.

E.g.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "project_id" {
  backend   = "gcs"
  workspace = "${terraform.workspace}"

  config = {
    bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
    prefix = "${var.prefix_project}"
    credentials = "${var.credentials}"  <- added
  }
}
```

Comment: missing 

config = {

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same error when trying to run terraform (version 1.1.5) commands in spite of having successfully authenticated via `gcloud auth login`.

Error message in my case:

> Error: storage.NewClient() failed: dialing: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

It turned out that I had to also authenticate via `gcloud auth application-default login` and was able to run terraform commands thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

﻿​Provide the service account credentials:

```
terraform {

  backend "gcs" {
    credentials = "myserviceaccount-credentials-file.json"
    bucket = "my-project-global-bucket"
    prefix = "terraform/state"
  }

}
```